# plot sideways density with ggplot2::stat_ydensity

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been making figures like the one below using a modified version of `geom_violin`:

[image: Plot with modified version of geom_violin]

However, I realize that this plot is probably achievable using `stat_ydensity` directly. Unfortunately, I can't get it working right:

```
ggplot(res.plot, aes(x = time, y = x,group = run)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.1) +
  stat_ydensity(aes(group = time), data = res.select, 
    geom = "density", color = "red")
```

[image: failed attempt with stat_ydensity]

I have tried using `geom = "path"` and `geom = "line"`, and tried different positions with e.g. `position = "identity"` and `position = position_dodge(width = 2)`, but can't produce anything like the top plot.

**Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?** Reprex for `res.plot` and `res.select` dataframes below:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
# markov chain parameters
mu = 8                           # cm/hr
sigma = 4                        # cm/sqrt(hr)
x0 = 3                           # initial condition
tmax = 200                       # end time
deltat = 10                      # time increment (hrs)
reps = 300                       # number of realizations

random_walk = function() 
  c(0, cumsum(mu*deltat + sigma*rnorm(n, sd = deltat))) + x0

# simulate random walks
n = tmax/deltat
res = cbind.data.frame(seq(0,tmax, by = deltat), replicate(reps, random_walk()))
names(res) = c("time", paste("run", seq(1, ncol(res) - 1)))
# format the data for plotting
res.plot = gather(res, run, x, -time)
# extract specific times to compute marginal densities
res.select = filter(res.plot, time %in% c(50, 150))
```

Comment: I think whatever you're doing now may suit you better. If you set your `geom = violin` instead of `density` it'll plot it as an entire violin, but you appear to be interested in plotting only the right face of the violin, correct?

Comment: @Anonymouscoward sure, I have a solution currently but it requires an almost- copy of `geom_violin` and the `GeomViolin` `ggproto` object, and therefore requires maintenance of that code if/when `ggplot2` evolves and adds complexity to sharing code with others. If this capability is already achievable using `stat_ydensity` I'd rather use that directly rather than create Frankenstein' geom.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an "answer" in that it does not solve the problem but it might help the OP understand why it's not working:

```
ggplot(res.plot, aes(x = time, y = x, group = run)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.1) +
  stat_ydensity(aes(group = time), data = res.select, 
    geom = "density", color = "red") -> gg

gb <- ggplot_build(gg)

str(gb$data[[2]])
## 'data.frame': 1024 obs. of  20 variables:
##  $ x          : num  50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 ...
##  $ density    : num  0.000139 0.000144 0.000149 0.000154 0.000159 ...
##  $ scaled     : num  0.0308 0.0319 0.033 0.0342 0.0354 ...
##  $ ndensity   : num  0.0308 0.0319 0.033 0.0342 0.0354 ...
##  $ count      : num  0.0417 0.0432 0.0447 0.0462 0.0478 ...
##  $ n          : int  300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 ...
##  $ y          : num  178 179 180 181 182 ...
##  $ group      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ PANEL      : Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ violinwidth: num  0.0308 0.0319 0.033 0.0342 0.0354 ...
##  $ ymin       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
##  $ ymax       : num  178 179 180 181 182 ...
##  $ xmin       : num  50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 ...
##  $ xmax       : num  50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 ...
##  $ colour     : chr  "red" "red" "red" "red" ...
##  $ fill       : chr  "#617a89" "#617a89" "#617a89" "#617a89" ...
##  $ weight     : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ alpha      : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
##  $ size       : num  0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...
##  $ linetype   : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Look at the values for `density` (and it's siblings). This is the computed density and — remember — the area under the curve of a density plot == 1. There's no option in `stat_ydensity()` like there is for `geom_density()` to do the math and get the counts for you instead.

You could try taking `gb$data[[2]]`, recompute the points for the path and manually add it in later. But, there's also nothing really wrong with keeping a local geom around and just putting a watch on ggplot2 releases to update when necessary. I do that all the time.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I was not clear in my post---I'm not looking to use count data, I just want to display the density line rather than doing a violin plot. Regardless of whether you set geom to `density` or `violin` (or `line`, `path`, for that matter) in `stat_ydensity`, it appears that the contents of `gb$data[[2]]` are identical---so I am wondering why `density` gets plotted so differently from the outline of `violin`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems impossible, since you need to map the calculated variable to `x` but `stat_ydensity()` needs `x` to calculate the values. It's a dead lock.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# markov chain parameters
mu = 8                           # cm/hr
sigma = 4                        # cm/sqrt(hr)
x0 = 3                           # initial condition
tmax = 200                       # end time
deltat = 10                      # time increment (hrs)
reps = 300                       # number of realizations

random_walk = function() 
  c(0, cumsum(mu*deltat + sigma*rnorm(n, sd = deltat))) + x0

# simulate random walks
n = tmax/deltat
res = cbind.data.frame(seq(0,tmax, by = deltat), replicate(reps, random_walk()))
names(res) = c("time", paste("run", seq(1, ncol(res) - 1)))
# format the data for plotting
res.plot = gather(res, run, x, -time)
# extract specific times to compute marginal densities
res.select = filter(res.plot, time %in% c(50, 150))

ggplot(res.plot, aes(x = time, y = x,group = run)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.1) +
  stat_ydensity(aes(group = time, x = stat(violinwidth)), data = res.select, 
                geom = "point", color = "red")
#> Error: stat_ydensity requires the following missing aesthetics: x
```

Of course, it's OK to map other variable than `x`.

```r
ggplot(res.plot, aes(x = time, y = x,group = run)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.1) +
  stat_ydensity(aes(group = time, size = stat(violinwidth)), data = res.select, 
                geom = "point", color = "red")
#> Warning: Width not defined. Set with `position_dodge(width = ?)`
```

[image]

It's also OK to use the variable without explicit mapping in Geom's internal functions. I guess `geom_ydensity()` uses this way. Maybe you need to create a new Geom for this?